# How to Use GetEnumerator()

Tags: linq

What is the use of `GetEnumerator()` in **linq**.

Can anyone explain to me how it works with a basic example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you even try to read some documentation before asking this question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[GetEnumerator()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator.aspx#Y600) returns object that can be used to iterate through the collection.

Let's say you have the following list of numbers:

```
var numbers = new List<Int32>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

and want all even numbers converted to a string, you could write the following method:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetEvenStrings(IEnumerable<Int32> source)
{
    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            if (enumerator.Current % 2 == 0)
                yield return enumerator.Current.ToString();
}
```

The [MoveNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext.aspx) method will have the [Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.current.aspx) property of the `Enumerator` point to the next element in the collection and will return `false` if there's no element left (otherwise `true`).

This is a very basic example of how to use an enumerator. A more complex and practical use is e.g. this [implementation](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/14/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-35-zip.aspx) of the `Zip` method:

```
private static IEnumerable<TResult> ZipImpl<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>( 
    IEnumerable<TFirst> first, 
    IEnumerable<TSecond> second, 
    Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> resultSelector) 
{ 
    using (IEnumerator<TFirst> iterator1 = first.GetEnumerator()) 
    using (IEnumerator<TSecond> iterator2 = second.GetEnumerator()) 
    { 
        while (iterator1.MoveNext() && iterator2.MoveNext()) 
        { 
            yield return resultSelector(iterator1.Current, iterator2.Current); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

(This code is from Jon Skeet's [Edulinq project](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx), which I highly recommend)

In this example, the `Enumerator` is used to iterate over two collections at the same time, resulting in a single collection.

---

Generally, you may want to use an `Enumerator` if you want to iterate over a collection step-by-step to apply some logic and you don't want to consume the entire collection first, since the collections could be using [deffered execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx).